# Unable to access DataGridViewRow cells by index

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to loop through two columns in a `DataGridView` and add them into a coordinate as below

```
foreach (DataGridView row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    double x = Convert.ToDouble(row["X"]);
    double y = Convert.ToDouble(row["Y"]);
    Coordinate c = new Coordinate(x, y);
    Point p = new Point(c);
    IFeature currentFeature = fs.AddFeature(p);
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        currentFeature.DataRow[i] = row[i];
    }
}
```

but I am encountring with following error:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow'

Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fairly simple - `DataGridViewRow` class does not expose an indexer. You need to access cells via its `Cells` collection. `row.Cells[i]` should probably do the trick:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
   currentFeature.DataRow[i] = row.Cells[i].Value as IConvertible;
}
```

Comment: Hi Morawski, I Update the code as double x = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["East"]); it did'nt complain at compiler buy I got this error message at run time:Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: Thanks, I update the code but this time I am getting error on for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    currentFeature.DataRow[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
                } and the error is :Cannot find column 0.! Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Comment: That's another problem now, and it lies outside of the scope of the code you posted. You need to debug it. How many cells does `currentFeature.DataRow` has? And `row`? You can't always escape from doing a minimum of debugging

Comment: well it is 150 rows (Two columns X and Y) I am not sure what do u mean by cell but they should be 300 together

Comment: Make sure (within the loop) that `currentFeature.DataRow.ItemArray.Length >= dataGridView1.Columns.Count`. If not, it means that `currentFeature.DataRow` is too short and you can't copy the contents of `row` into it because they won't fit.

Comment: Thanks Morawski, it works now but I do not know why I am getting 151 result instead of 150!?

Comment: I have no plausible way of knowing that really, maybe there's header row or something. Thanks for accepting the answer!

Answer (score 2):

`DataGridViewRow` is not the collection. You need to run this on the `Cells` collection :)

Comment: Hi Wesley,  Thanks for your comment but can you please give me some more information about this?

Comment: Sure. @Morawski updated his code on his answer. He had it right before me, be sure to mark his as the answer!